# What is the '+' in find command for?

Tags: find

I have some times come across the use of trailing `+` while using unix commands like `find`.

Example from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718907/1135954) -

```
find . -exec touch -t 201007162310.00 {} +
```

Please help me understand the use of this.

Answer (score 10):

From `man find`:

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> This variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the
> selected files, but the command line  is  built  by appending  each
> selected  file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the
> command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The command
> line is built in much the same way that  xargs  builds  its  command
> lines.  Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the command.  The
> command is executed in the starting directory.

For example with `find -exec touch -t 201007162310.00 {} +`, if the `find` command without the `-exec` gives you the files `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`, it will execute:

```
touch -t 201007162310.00 1.txt
touch -t 201007162310.00 2.txt
touch -t 201007162310.00 3.txt
```

with `-exec ... {} \;`, and

```
touch -t 201007162310.00 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

with `-exec ... {} +`.

The latter version is faster due to a (much) smaller number of new processes needed yet it is less portable (not all `find` implementations support it). And of course, if the command you try to `-exec` doesn't support receiving multiple files as arguments, it won't work.

Comment: `-exec {} +` is POSIX and standard. For once, only the GNU find was not supporting it until `findutils` 4.2.12 (2005). `-exec {} +` was added to SysV some time in the 80s by David Korn.